# Does SQLite come with Mac OS X?

Tags: database, macos, sqlite

Is SQLite pre-installed on Mac OS X or not?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge - yes.

Comment: Which version of OSX?  Currently there is leopard, snow leopard and lion.

Comment: i think is snow leopard (lap is not too old). how i can check if is installed?

Comment: open Terminal and type `sqlite3`

Comment: I believe from Tiger forward, /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib

Answer (score 5):

OS X 10.4 and up ship with [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite).

> Apple adopted it as an option in Mac OS X's Core Data API from the
>   original implementation in Mac OS X 10.4 onwards, and also for
>   administration of videos and songs on the iPhone.